# How can I sort ls by owner and group?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, ls, syntax

How can I list directories with ls and sort them by their owner and group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $3, $4, $8}' | sort
```

It will print the user name, the group name and the file name, provided that the file name doesn't contain spaces. Alternatively, you can type:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $3, $4, $0}' | sort
```

This will print the user name, group name and the full `ls -l` output, sorted by the user name first, then the group name, then whatever `ls -l` prints first.

Note that depending on your distribution, the actual column numbers may differ. I tried mine in SUSE and coreutils version 5.2.1.

There are probably better, more elaborate solutions, but this is the simplest one, and will work most of the time.

Comment: s/row numbers/column numbers/

Answer (score 8):

As petersohn said, something similar to:

- `ls -l | awk '{print $3, $4, $8, $0}' | sort | column -t`
  added the `$8` and the `column -t` for pretty print

Or even better:

- `ls -l | sort -k 3` - sorts by owner and by default sorts the next field (group) and on
- `ls -l | sort -k 4,4 -k 3` - sorts by group and then by owner
- `ls -l | sort -k 3,3 -k 8` - sorts by owner and then by filename

***Note:*** the comma is the terminator field so `3,3` starts and end at field 3 `3,5` sorts from fields 3 to 5.

Comment: To sort by group and then by owner I had to add -b to ignore leading blanks, otherwise the list would be sorted by the string length of the owner name.